# how to Lodash groupBy and sort by date and time

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have object of arrays looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": [
        {
            "title": "14 июня",
            "data": [
                {
                    "_id": "5eb173e8cf23760430d70453",
                    "patientId": {
                        "_id": "5eb171ba86b4e90174c2b393",
                        "avatar": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1131446033110765570/e9xAXFKd_400x400.jpg",
                        "fullName": "Мешок Скостями",
                        "gender": "male",
                        "email": "valero@ever.com",
                        "phone": "996312123456",
                        "createdAt": "2020-05-05T14:01:30.876Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-06-12T16:56:03.555Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "dentNumber": 14,
                    "diagnosis": "Лечение зубов",
                    "price": 500,
                    "date": "2020-06-14",
                    "time": "10:00",
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-05T14:10:48.482Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-06-13T11:14:31.001Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5edd34cf300fc60efcebcfa3",
                    "patientId": {
                        "_id": "5ecc0c526d756216802ca0b4",
                        "avatar": "",
                        "fullName": "Густаво",
                        "gender": "male",
                        "email": "3.1313@mail.ru",
                        "phone": "996700126646",
                        "createdAt": "2020-05-25T18:20:02.874Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-05-25T18:20:02.874Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "dentNumber": 5,
                    "diagnosis": "Лечение ",
                    "price": 4500,
                    "date": "2020-06-14",
                    "time": "08:40",
                    "createdAt": "2020-06-07T18:41:19.126Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-06-13T12:51:49.213Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "5 мая",
            "data": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ec0479a67d7381c348bfbd9",
                    "patientId": {
                        "_id": "5ec0360e67618614345bea2b",
                        "avatar": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554175308-e37121817631?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=400",
                        "fullName": "Valeria",
                        "gender": "female",
                        "email": "valeria@ever.com",
                        "phone": "996555123456",
                        "createdAt": "2020-05-16T18:50:54.486Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-05-18T17:51:13.207Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "dentNumber": 11,
                    "diagnosis": "Осмотр",
                    "price": 0,
                    "date": "2020-05-05",
                    "time": "11:00",
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-16T20:05:46.332Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-05-16T20:05:46.332Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

it is already grouped by date so every array has a title of its day, BUT
I need to sort by time in every this day-group and sort all of days by asc or desc to render them sorted, please help me to find out solution, there is my controller code and [link](https://github.com/ArturScwaiberov/react-native-backend) to github project:

```
const all = function (req, res) {
    Appointment.find({})
        .populate('patientId')
        .exec(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: err,
                })
            }

            res.json({
                status: 'success',
                message: reduce(
                    groupBy(docs, 'date'),
                    (result, value, key) => {
                        result = [...result, { title: dayjs(key).locale('ru').format('D MMMM'), data: value }]
                        return result
                    },
                    []
                ),
            })
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few days of torment I solved it like this:
I did orderBy inside of groupBy, so first parameter of groupBy is sorted array

```
            res.json({
                status: 'success',
                message: reduce(
                    groupBy(
                        orderBy(docs, [
                            function (item) {
                                return new Date(item.date + ' ' + item.time)
                            },
                        ]),
                        'date'
                    ),
                    (result, value, key) => {
                        result = [...result, { title: dayjs(key).locale('ru').format('D MMMM'), data: value }]
                        return result
                    },
                    []
                ),
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this:

```js
var data =[
                {
                    "_id": "5eb173e8cf23760430d70453",
                    "patientId": {
                        "_id": "5eb171ba86b4e90174c2b393",
                        "avatar": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1131446033110765570/e9xAXFKd_400x400.jpg",
                        "fullName": "Мешок Скостями",
                        "gender": "male",
                        "email": "valero@ever.com",
                        "phone": "996312123456",
                        "createdAt": "2020-05-05T14:01:30.876Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-06-12T16:56:03.555Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "dentNumber": 14,
                    "diagnosis": "Лечение зубов",
                    "price": 500,
                    "date": "2020-06-14",
                    "time": "10:00",
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-05T14:10:48.482Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-06-13T11:14:31.001Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5edd34cf300fc60efcebcfa3",
                    "patientId": {
                        "_id": "5ecc0c526d756216802ca0b4",
                        "avatar": "",
                        "fullName": "Густаво",
                        "gender": "male",
                        "email": "3.1313@mail.ru",
                        "phone": "996700126646",
                        "createdAt": "2020-05-25T18:20:02.874Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-05-25T18:20:02.874Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "dentNumber": 5,
                    "diagnosis": "Лечение ",
                    "price": 4500,
                    "date": "2020-06-14",
                    "time": "08:40",
                    "createdAt": "2020-06-07T18:41:19.126Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-06-13T12:51:49.213Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }
        ]
 data.sort((a,b)=> new Date(a.createdAt) - new Date(b.createdAt));      
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Im trying do it in `all` function

`groupBy(docs, 'date'),
     (result, value, key) => {
      result = [...result, { title: dayjs(key).locale('ru').format('D MMMM'), data: value }]
      return result
     },
     []`

Comment: You can sort the `result` of  this function using `sort` as I showed. Isn't it?

Comment: @ArturShvaiberov try now. There was a small typo. In `new Date(a.createdAt) - new Date(b.createdAt))` instead of `b.createdAt`, I had put `a.createdAt` twice

Comment: Or you could even use `_.sortBy(data, 'createdAt')` if you wanna sort it with *lodash* only

Comment: yes I have been read about _.sortBy(data, 'createdAt') but I cannot to emplement this stuff to my code.. Im sorry, Im just studying and maybe Im asking stupid questions..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215905/discussion-between-abgr-and-arturshvaiberov).